# What criteria must be satisfied to make a type CLS Compliant

Tags: c#, .net

How can I make an assembly / class to be CLS compliant? What criteria should they have? And if I just annotate my assembly with **[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]** and one of my type is not CLS compliant, will it affect the behaviors of the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link above has better to be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2c7tshk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for .net 4.

Anyway, Code Analysis or FxCop is your good friend for writing cls compliant code, along for other QA issues.

Answer (score 3):

Just let the compiler tell you about it.  Declare the assembly CLS-compliant with the attribute, put it anywhere inside a source code file:

```
  [assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]
```

And rebuild your code.  When you get warning CS3001 then it will tell you exactly what is wrong with the declaration.  For example:

```
public class NotCompliant {
    public void Foo(uint x) { }
}
```

Generates:

> warning CS3001: Argument type 'uint' is not CLS-compliant